# R Merging two dataframes of different lengths, repeating rows of the shorter until a value change in the first

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'd like to merge two differently sized df together. Both have timestamps, but the timestamps do not overlap. I can get the timestamps from the small df into the larger df easily enough, but my goal is to repeat the rows of the smaller df until the next timestamp and parameter change as indicated by the smaller df. A minimum reproducible example to demonstrate [EDIT based on comments below]:

```
set.seed(123)
gratingspeed <- c(sample(c(-3:3), 10, replace=TRUE))
gratingfreq <- sample(c(-2, -1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 2), 10, replace=TRUE)
timestamp <- runif(10, min=0, max=25)
timestamp[1] <- 0
stimuli <- data.frame(gratingspeed, gratingfreq, timestamp)
stimuli <- arrange(stimuli, stimuli$timestamp)
timemultiplier <- c(rep(c(-1,1), 5))
stimuli <- cbind(timemultiplier, stimuli)
stimuli$dfid <- row_number(stimuli$timestamp)

trackingx <- runif(25, min=0, max=800)
trackingy <- runif(25, min=0, max=800)
boutsuccess <- vector <- sample(c(rep(TRUE, 23), rep(FALSE, 2)), 25 ,replace = T)
timestamp <- c(1:25)
trackingdata <- cbind(trackingx, trackingy, boutsuccess, timestamp)
trackingdata <- as.data.frame(trackingdata)
trackingdata$dfid <- NA
```

I found that merge(sort=FALSE) is the best way to do this, but I need a common column to merge these df. I built a dfid column that acts as an index for this process like so:

```
trialdummy <- stimuli
trialdummy[c(1:3)] <- NA  
names(trialdummy)[1:3] <- c("trackingx", "trackingy", "boutsuccess")
trialdata <- rbind(trialdummy, trackingdata)
trialdata <- trialdata %>%
  arrange(timestamp)
```

But I need the dfid indices to repeat until the value changes. Perhaps involving rle(). Any help with either building the proper dfid column so I can use merge(sort=FALSE), or a better way to merge the two original df would be much appreciated. Tidyverse answers appreciated, but not necessary. Thank you!

Comment: As a minor note, `trackingdata <- cbind(...); trackingdata <- as.data.frame(trackingdata)` is an anti-pattern that should be avoided. It's shorter and safer to use `trackingdata <- data.frame(...)` directly. Here it doesn't really matter because all your data is numeric, but if you have mixed data types it can cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Not sure why you're getting that error; when I generate my df both have 5 columns of data. Looking through it now.

Comment: Edited version going up with streamlined data.frame() and error fixed, hopefully this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `tidyr::fill`

```
library(tidyr)
trialdata %>% 
  fill(dfid, .direction = "down")
#    trackingx   trackingy boutsuccess timestamp dfid
# 1         NA          NA          NA  0.000000    1
# 2  721.83924 102.0253202           1  1.000000    1
# 3  552.56422 602.6462914           1  2.000000    1
# 4  636.37393 716.0362873           1  3.000000    1
# 5         NA          NA          NA  3.677841    2
# 6   19.69095 299.5702207           1  4.000000    2
# 7  382.23678 532.0921557           1  5.000000    2
# 8  606.76763  75.8725287           1  6.000000    2
# 9  173.12635 307.1757102           1  7.000000    2
# 10        NA          NA          NA  7.228993    3
# 11 254.54481 219.5069157           1  8.000000    3
# 12 185.30063 651.7120311           1  9.000000    3
# ...
```

If you're using `dplyr` already, `bind_rows` is a more flexible and more efficient alternative to `rbind`.